# two composite keys from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database, I need to create a new `closure` table (called `closure_new`) that integrates a two column foreign key to another table, `concept`.  This means adding rows to `closure_new` that are not in `closure`.  How do I set up the SQL to accomplish this?

Here is my first attempt at the code for populating `closure_new`:

```
INSERT INTO `closure_new`
SELECT o.subtypeId, d.id, d.effectiveTime
  FROM concept d
  JOIN closure o
  ON o.subtypeId = d.id;
```

Note that my first attempt only addresses `subtypeId/subtype_effectiveTime` and might not address it completely.  The SQL also needs to incorporate `supertypeId/supertype_effectiveTime`.  How do I write the SQL to populate the `closure_new` table with records for each of the `effectiveTime` values associated with each `subtypeId` and each `supertypeId`?

Here is the `concept` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `concept` (
`id` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`effectiveTime` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`some other fields`,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`effectiveTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here is the old `closure` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `closure` (
    `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `subtypeId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
    `supertypeId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Here is the `closure_new` table that needs to be populated with the script I started to write above:

```
CREATE TABLE `closure_new` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`subtypeId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
`subtype_effectiveTime` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`supertypeId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
`supertype_effectiveTime` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
FOREIGN KEY (`supertypeId`, `supertype_effectiveTime`) references concept(`id`, `effectiveTime`),
FOREIGN KEY (`subtypeId`, `subtype_effectiveTime`) references concept(`id`, `effectiveTime`)
); ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand what you're after, but how about:

```
INSERT INTO `closure_new` (subtypeId, subtype_effectiveTime, supertypeId, supertype_effectiveTime)
SELECT subCon.id, subCon.effectiveTime, superCon.id, superCOn.effectiveTimed.effectiveTime
  FROM closure o, concept subCon, concept superCon
 where subcon.Id = o.subtypeId and supercon.Id = o.supertypeId
```

Or possibly, you could just `create view` with that select statement.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  I ran the other responder's code and it added over 70 million rows to the new table before I had to kill the MySQL command line client and reboot the system to get it to stop.  The result is that windows will no longer start the MySQL windows service, which essentially shuts down my development project until I get the windows MySQL service to launch again.  I posted this as another question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816585/drop-table-in-mysql-from-outside

Comment: Crikey!  Once you get your server back up, do please try the above, but before you run the full `Insert` command, try it with the Select clause being `select count(*)`, to see what will happen.

Comment: I ran the above code and it created an expected number of new rows in 31 minutes.  I am therefore marking this as the answer.  Thank you, and +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
insert into closure_new 
(subtypeId, subtype_effectiveTime, supertypeId, supertype_effectiveTime) 
select cl.id, co.effectiveTime, co.id, co.effectiveTime from closure cl inner join concept co
```

Your data better match or you will have some foreign key constraint issues

Comment: i'm not sure what your data looks like but perhaps you're looking for a `left outer join` then ?

Comment: This code corrupted my database.  The insert statement ran for over 24 hours and inserted over 260 GB of invalid data into the new table.  I had to stop the script forcibly by killing the MySQL command line client and restarting the machine.  I then had to spend a couple days running MySQL dump and restore operations that took 24 hours each before I was able to even start an uncorrupted windows MySQL service in order to delete the 260 GB table that was created.  These 3 operations alone totaled 72 hours.  By contrast, the code from the other responder ran in 31 minutes.

Comment: hmmm my query is incomplete and missing the where at the end. probably a wrong copy/paste from the sql window. i never thought it could corrupt your data though... but i had tested it out before pasting it here so i'm pretty sure it works.