# Drop table in MySQL from outside

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not able to get Windows 7 to open the MySQL service (error 1053) after running a poorly planned script which ran for 24 hours without completing.  The script simply inserted rows into a table `some_table_name`.

I am trying various ways of getting Windows 7 to start the service, but I imagine the problem might include the 70 million rows of data that were added to `some_table_name` while the script was running.  How can I do this under the conditions when MySQL is not running as a Windows 7 service?

Here is the command that I want the database to execute:

```
use my_dbase_name;
drop table some_table_name;
```

Comment: If service is not running then how will you execute that command?

Comment: @Rahul That is my question, precisely.

Comment: That's my answer precisely ... NO, you can't do that. You can't run a DB command against some database table when your DB engine itself not running. Who will execute that command?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to start the service?

Comment: @Rahul I deleted the `ib_logfile*` files, and made some changes to `my-default.ini`.  I also restarted the computer a few times and continued to try to restart the service.  I am not sure what else to try except simply deleting the table that was blown up by the bad script.

Comment: @Tom I am getting `error 1053`

Comment: You could try increasing the `innodb_log_file_size` in my-default.ini, unless that's something you've already tried

Comment: @Tom I made the following changes, but the service still will not start: `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 100M` , `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M`, `innodb_log_file_size = 50M`

Comment: Try deleting the `*.err` files as well and then do a reboot.

Comment: @Rahul where do I find the `*.err` files?

Comment: @CodeMed, well I mean `yourserver_name.err` file. should be present in installation path.

Comment: @Rahul Where do I find that?  This is a development machine, it is running on the localhost while under development.

Comment: @CodeMed, it should be in DATA directory. same location where ib* files are present.

Comment: @Rahul There are no `.err` files in the data directory.  There is an `ibdata1` file there tho.  There are also two subdirectories, but neither of the subdirectories has any `.err` files either. I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: @Rahul I have never created a `my.ini` file, so I assume that `my-default.ini` is doing that job.  `my-default.ini` does not specify a data directory for the error files. There are only two uncommented lines in `my-default.ini` in addition to the three lines that I added (shown above).  I am using this project to learn MySQL, and would really appreciate help.  My entire project is on hold until I can get the database engine to start again. People are on me for deliverables that I cant start working on until the database starts.

Comment: @CodeMed, not sure whether I will be of much help here. would suggest you to post the same question in `http://serverfault.com`. BTW, are you sure your MySQL service is not already started?

Comment: @Rahul Thank you. I am not able to start the MySQL command line client, so I think that means the service has not started.  The `ibdata1` file is 76,000,000KB in size, which would seem to me to be a problem.  I did follow your advice and post a question at serverfault, but I am not sure if anyone reads those posting. stack overflow gets a ton of people answering sql questions.

Comment: @CodeMed, are you windows or unix machine? What is RAM size?

Comment: @CodeMed, do also check whether you have privilege to start the service? may be your password have expired.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you! I am the administrator.  I have all privileges on the machine and on the database.  My posting got voted out of serverfault but they said to put it on dba.stackexchange, so I have done that.  I am just not sure if anyone reads those questions.

Comment: @CodeMed, they will .. give it sometime. Sorry man, but I am out of idea; I am a developer ... really don't have much idea about this things. Whatever I knew ... I commented above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the means, try running the service on another machine, then re-create the schema.  Then under the data directory for your DB, you should find files pertaining to each table in your DB, possibly with indexes, too.  You might be able to replace the bad, corrupt file (hint - it will be the big one ;) with a good one containing no rows, from your 'clean' instance.

Comment: +1 and thank you for submitting an answer.  I was not able to run it on another machine, but I did use `innodb_force_recovery=5` to force the windows MySQL service to start.  Then I ran `mysqldump`, then backed up and deleleted the database files in the `/MySQL/data` directory before running a `restore` operation of the dumped file.  All these steps restored an uncorrupted copy of the database, so that I could delete the 260 GB table that had been created by the bad script.